# Robocopy encrypted file using Window 2008 R2 with parameter "/efsraw" show The interface is unknown and encrypted folder failed to copy over to target

Tags: windows, command, robocopy

I am using a robocopy version XP027 Version to copy one encrypted folder from (ABC-S-001) to the target server (bbc-s-002) was encounted the interface is unknown in the logfile.

as i using the server window 2008 R2 to run the robocopy version XP027 for the below scripts

as i know we only can using window 2008 R2 to using the parameted "/efsraw" to copy the encrypted file. but its seem not work as the result was only copy the folder and file with 0 size in the target direcctory.

My robocopy scripts

```
robocopy "\\ABC-S-001\e$\DATA\Business-001\Projects\encrypted folder" "\\bbc-s-002\F$\DATA\Business-abc\Projects\encrypted folder" /EFSRAW /E /V /SEC /PURGE /MIR /Z /NP /R:1 /W:1 /LOG+:"c:\Temp\encrypted folder.txt"
```

Logfile show

```
\\bbc-s-002\F$\DATA\Business-abc\Projects\encrypted folder\Delete_Application.htmThe interface is unknown
```

PS\ I would like to know is that any solution to copy the encrypted file into another location?
is that my robocopy parameter was not set appropriate?

I just need the specific encrypted file "encrypted folder" and its subfolder and file are successfully copy over with data size.

appreciated that if someone professional are able to answer my question.

Many thanks in advance. its abit urgent to get this issue resolved.

Comment: Perhaps NTFS encryption is disabled on the target server?

Comment: Hi Harry Johnston, would you please advice how to check whether the NTFS encryption is disabled or enable from d server?

Comment: There are various reasons why NTFS encryption might be disabled.  The simplest approach is probably to try encrypting a test file, preferably while logged onto the destination server locally.

Comment: @RayChai, Does this help: http://www.geektank.net/2011/08/using-robocopy-to-copy-efs-files/

Answer (score 0):

Your command should be something like

**robocopy source destination /COPY:DATS /MIR /EFSRAW /R:2 /W:0 /E /ETA**

Comment: Why does this work? Answers should include enough explanation to bridge the lack of understanding.